# Is there a way to get HTML divisions of a given class that must necessarily be contiguous?

Tags: python, html, regex, web-scraping

My problem is that in a situation like the example below, I need to get TEXT#1 and TEXT#2 in class=cls_003 and store them as separate strings. I am currently using Python, BeautifulSoup and regex to open the web page, and re.findall to get the required divs and then get the text using BeautifulSoup. 
Is there a better way to do it?

**HTML page I am trying to scrape:**

```
<div style="xxxx" class="cls_003"><span class="cls_003">----TEXT #1---</span></div>
<div style="xxxx" class="cls_003"><span class="cls_003">----TEXT #1---</span></div>

<div style="yyyy" class="cls_007"><span class="cls_007">----UNNECESSARY TEXT---</span></div>
<div style="yyyy" class="cls_007"><span class="cls_007">----UNNECESSARY TEXT---</span></div>class="cls_009">'r'End</span></div>

<div style="xxxx" class="cls_003"><span class="cls_003">----TEXT #2---</span></div>
<div style="xxxx" class="cls_003"><span class="cls_003">----TEXT #2---</span></div>
</div>class="cls_009">'r'End</span></div>
```

**Python code I currently have running**

```
soup_string = str(soup)

results = re.findall(r'(?m)<div style="xxxx" class="cls_003">.*?class="cls_009">'
                             r'End</span></div>', soup_string, flags=re.S)

soup2 = BeautifulSoup(results, features="lxml")
for result in results:
    result_parsed = soup2.findAll("div", {"class": "cls_003"})
    for q in result_parsed:
        print(q.text)
    print('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use regex. here is my solution:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

doc = '''<div style="xxxx" class="cls_003"><span class="cls_003">----TEXT #1---</span></div>
<div style="xxxx" class="cls_003"><span class="cls_003">----TEXT #1---</span></div>

<div style="yyyy" class="cls_007"><span class="cls_007">----UNNECESSARY TEXT---</span></div>
<div style="yyyy" class="cls_007"><span class="cls_007">----UNNECESSARY TEXT---</span></div>class="cls_009">'r'End</span></div>

<div style="xxxx" class="cls_003"><span class="cls_003">----TEXT #2---</span></div>
<div style="xxxx" class="cls_003"><span class="cls_003">----TEXT #2---</span></div>
</div>class="cls_009">'r'End</span></div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(doc, features="html.parser")
results = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "cls_003"})
resultsList = []
for result in results:
    resultsList.append(result.text)

print(f'Result set 1: {resultsList[0]+resultsList[1]}')
print(f'Result set 2: {resultsList[2]+resultsList[3]}')
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You are correct, but the thing is I need TEXT#1 and TEXT#2 as separate strings. Getting them together isn't exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: What do you mean by separate text? How to separate them would satisfy the needs?

Comment: Note that there are two divs of cls_003 in the beginning and two in the end. I need the text in the first two cls_003 divs concatenated and stored separately. And then I need the text in the last two cls_003 divs concatenated and stored separately as another string.

Comment: @StephenKingston I have updated the code. Now it creates a list of all the results and then concatenates the same way you asked for.

Comment: haha...thank you for the effort you put in. But it should work for a more general case - It is not necessarily 2 cls_003 divs in one place.  Might be any number of cls_003 divs and it should still work.